# My css background color is not changing, why?

Tags: html, css

I use glitch.com and the background color is not changing for some reason I used the same code in other projects and it worked

css:

```
 body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:rgb(40, 48, 54);
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Can you give us some more details? Otherwise, I think you changed the `background-color` somewhere else.

Comment: there could be many reasons, some of them are that you are looking at the wrong page or you are setting the background in the wrong css file; or your css got cached by the browser; provide some more context

Answer (score 0):

You might be setting the background color somewhere else,  if you really want to try and override it without finding it make it `!important` like this

```
 body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:rgb(40, 48, 54) !important;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
```

Comment: Hi John, Is it maybe the '!important' (please note I use # not RGB) and try to use RGBA isn't supposed to be there, at the end of 'h1' there needs to be an RBRACE '}' and try  'background' instead of 'background-color', these are just some suggestions,

Comment: @RingGamesCompany yes it could 100% be declared as `background` and not `background-color` so I suggest OP to try both. thanks for your input.

Comment: no problem. No problem at all

Comment: by '#' I meant 'hex'

Answer (score 0):

if you are in [glitch.com](https://glitch.com) you have to use this code
`.cHtQlM {
    background-color: red;
}`